# How to use a list contained within a function

Tags: r

I'm sure this is bad function design but here goes...

I have a function that maps some terms to some other terms. The details are not relevant here.

In the function I have a list of characters. I want to use this list for a different purpose. How can I refer to the list contained within a function?

For example:

```
TermMapping<-function(param){



###The list I want to refer to
 tofind <-
    paste(
      c(
        "Ascending","Descending","Sigmoid","Rectum","Transverse",
        "Caecum","Splenic","Ileum","Rectosigmoid",
        "Ileocaecal","Hepatic","Colon","Terminal","Terminal Ileum",
        "Ileoanal","Prepouch","Pouch","Anastomosis",
        "Stomach","Antrum","Duodenum","Oesophagus","GOJ"
      ),
      collapse = "|"
    )

###something done to param here- details not included but it uses the list above.....


return(dataframe)
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two options I can think of:

1. If you need the list for multiple purposes, why is it inside the function? You can define the list outside the function (maybe as its own function), and then pass the list as a parameter.
2. You can return the list as part of your function. You're function returns the `dataframe`, so you could change your return value to return both the df and list.

   ```
   TermMapping<-function(param){



   ###The list I want to refer to
   tofind <-
     paste(
       c(
   "Ascending","Descending","Sigmoid","Rectum","Transverse",
   "Caecum","Splenic","Ileum","Rectosigmoid",
   "Ileocaecal","Hepatic","Colon","Terminal","Terminal Ileum",
   "Ileoanal","Prepouch","Pouch","Anastomosis",
   "Stomach","Antrum","Duodenum","Oesophagus","GOJ"
   ),
   collapse = "|"
   )

   ###something done to param here- details not included but it uses the list above.....


   return(list(my_df = dataframe,
       myList = tofind))
   }
   ```